# Electro harmonix Mel 9

Tags: guitar, effects

I love this pedal but I do have a few issues that would make it hard to use live. When you hit the button and disengage immediately cuts the effect, there's no bleed that's awkward. I'll probably switch out the button to a soft switch because that loud clunk is awful when you're playing live. Acoustically. Can I use a volume pedal after the effect to control the volume of the effect? Without affecting the overall volume. Thus leaving it always on?

Comment: "There's no bleed that's awkward." Do you mean that there's no awkward bleed, or do you mean "There's no bleed. That's awkward."?

Comment: Yeah sorry that was bad grammar. What I meant is sustain after pushing the button to disengage. I have a shimmer pedal that after you disengage the effect fades and it's nice when you start playing clean acoustic to have that fade behind it.

Comment: Please consider putting that in the post itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, get a volume pedal and a pedal that mixes two inputs to one output (Sweetwater has several including two around USD 100). Then use the separate wet and dry outputs of the Mel 9 and run the wet through the volume pedal and then both into the mixer pedal.

If your amp has two inputs, you can just use them instead of getting a separate mixer pedal.